# Lightbox2 - Multiple Images, One Click

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

I am currently using Lightbox 2 (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) and this is all working fine, however I need a slight tweak.

I want to display all the images vertically when a thumbnail is clicked. So if I have 3 images all using the same rel="lightbox[whatever]" I want them all to output. I don't want the "Image 1 of 5" with next and prev buttons.

I searched all over and couldn't find a solution. IF anyone has any ideas, snippets or external URLs it would be great appreciated.

Code Example:

```
<a href="resources/images/ClassicCarriers/ClassicCarriers1.jpg" rel="lightbox[classicCarriers]" title="">
    <img src="Resources/Images/classicCarriers_grey.jpg" class="recentWork" title="Classic Carriers" alt="Classic Carriers"/>
</a>
<a href="resources/images/ClassicCarriers/ClassicCarriers2.jpg" rel="lightbox[classicCarriers]" title=""></a>
<a href="resources/images/ClassicCarriers/ClassicCarriers3.jpg" rel="lightbox[classicCarriers]" title=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox to achieve what you want. Check the following code

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" width="100px">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" width="100px">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" width="100px">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('#container img').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.colorbox({
        href: '#container',
        inline: true
     });    

  });
});
```

Now when you click on any of the images all 3 will be shown in colorbox.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/E5Eft/2/)
    ​

```
​
```

Comment: I just want to see 1 thumbnail, then on click in a lightbox I see large image1 2 and 3.

Comment: almost there! I have about 10 thumbnails on the page, I need a way to have them all work liek that without duplicating that function for each one. Can we use the rel="" at all? My JS is terrible so I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Try [fancy box](http://fancybox.net/).  Instead of attaching the effect directly to images, attach it to an HTML containing the three images.